# How to best utilize Zz'Rot Portal and banner of command as a support

Tags: league-of-legends

I tend to play squishy supports, right now mostly sorraka (yeah, not many seem to play her, but I've always been a healer at heart).  I like banner of command, and am just now looking at zz'rot.  However, I want to best figure out how to use them.

I have a few questions, first, when would you prioritize one over the other?  I know how to prioritize the base stats, but in term of actives (and passive for zz'rot) are there situations where you would consider one more powerful then the other?

Secondly, how would you use their active, particularly zz'rots.  I mostly use banner of command as a straight forward split-push tool on a lane I'm not going to stay in, but zz'rot is a little more complex then "promote a minion while running from base after recall" sort of logic.

In general, what cool alternatives may I be missing in exploiting these abilities?

Comment: Why would you build zz'rots on Soraka? It's designed for tanks.

Comment: You should just go full utility with soraka, since if you build tank, you'll be taking more dmg for healing other teammates

Answer (score 1):

To start, lets take a look at each item.
**Banner of Command:**

> Stats: +10% cooldown reduction +60 ability power +200 health +20 magic
>   resistance Aura    UNIQUE – LEGION: Grants nearby allies +20 magic
>   resistance and +75% base health regeneration Active    UNIQUE – PROMOTE:
>   Greatly increases the power of a lane minion and grants it immunity to
>   magic damage. 120 second cooldown (1200 range).

Reason to pick it: 
With the presumption that you have either one or the other, Banner of Command provides stats that would be used better on Soraka than ZZ rot would. +200 HP and the aura give your team additional healing and allows you to be more effective at saving team members rather than topping them up constantly. The magic resist as well would be much more useful against primarily AP comps. 
Remember however, the minion summoned is a *single unit.*

**ZZ-rot**

> Stats +60 armor
>   +60 magic resistance
>   +100% base health regeneration Passive    UNIQUE - POINT RUNNER: Grants +30% bonus movement speed that builds up over 2 seconds when near turrets (including fallen turrets) or Void Gates. Active     Unique
>   Active: Spawns a Void Gate at target location for 150 seconds. Every 4
>   seconds the gate creates a volatile Voidspawn that travels down the
>   nearest lane, attacking enemy minions and exploding when attacking
>   structures, but ignoring champions and void targets. 150 second
>   cooldown.  The first and every fourth Voidspawn gain damage equal to
>   100% of your armor + 100% of your magic resistance.

Reason to pick it:
The resistances are much more powerful and give you regen which you need to keep topped up, However you shouldn't be taking damage as back line. The point runner passive also gives you(lets say as soraka) more speed when you're kiting back with your team, or simply running. The advantage of zz-rot is that it doesn't simply enpower a *single unit*. What i mean by that is, it creates several units, and as a result, might not be great against a team with good waveclear, as opposed to the enpowered minion which would take more time from an enemy who went off to another lane to deal with the wave. 
My primary reason for considering this item would be if you were ahead and sieging the enemy base as "exploding on enemy strucutres) can do tons of good damage. Picking banner of command would give your team additional pressure during the mid game where rotations are significant. The additonal lane pressure could win a teamfight easily. Within the close proximity of the enemy base, the enchanced minion is much less effective.

Considerations with "mostly Soraka". 
If you're playing soraka, you should know that you reasonably can't 1v1 anyone on the enemy team. Your abilities are better used with teammates. Zzrot from a mid game perspective has limited range, and requires you to go to that lane. As opposed to banner, where you can simply pop it after you recall. Because of that, for you, i would pick banner of command. The inability of soraka to roam safely alone is simply too risky for ZZ-rot to be worth it.

TLDR; 
Banner of command if you're going Soraka.

Comment: ZZ'Rot minions scale with resistances, and if you're playing Raka support you don't have the cash (or the slots) to invest heavily in those stats.

Comment: @henrebotha That isn't a huge issue. There are individuals that build Tank Sorakam, focused primarily on "topping up" teammates rather than saving their lives with burst heal. 
The key is mainly in the active they bring along which has substantial value in terms of map pressure.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim B said, Zz-rot portal may not be the best item for Soraka. Not only is split-pushing not her forte, but ZZ'rot portal does not give you worthwhile stats. Soraka does not scale well with high armor or MR, and these stats are just not as useful on her as other support items or more AP.

Obviously being harder to kill is a good trait, but you need to look at it at from a larger context. What stats are you giving up to get those extra 50 armor and MR? Soraka shouldn't be in the front line, so high defensive stats are wasted on her. Odds are, you would be more useful to your team with a different item than zz'rot. Remember, you only have 6 item slots, so make them count.

In most cases, sticking to the suggested item builds on sites such as probuilds.net will give you the best results. Ultimately, Zz'rot is not worth buying on soraka almost ever. Banner of command has it's place on her, especially when the other team has more than 2 AP waveclear type champs (Xerath, Ziggs, etc).

Answer (score 0):

How ive seen people use zzrot: if you have an inhib down you can put it near that lane to slow the enemy lane from pushing untill your inhib respawns.